# Is there any way to create a sticky footer in xaml?

Tags: xaml, footer, sticky

I know you can do a sticky footer in css, is there any way to do it in xaml?  Or to use css in xaml to do the same thing?  I'm brand new to xaml, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65790870/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-sticky-footer-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using DockPanels.

Comment: A better way to do it would be to use a grid layout and set the vertical alignment in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for a Grid as I find them easier to extend if your layout changes or you add more controls:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Label at the top"/>


    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Label at the bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

There's a decent tutorial [here](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html)

Comment: This is not a sticky footer, this is a fixed footer at the bottom.