# Is there any way to create a sticky footer in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, footer, sticky

I would like to have a sticky footer in WPF.

This is the only question that I found on this topic:
[Is there any way to create a sticky footer in xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670495/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-sticky-footer-in-xaml)

But the answer creates a **fixed** footer, not a *sticky* footer:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Label at the top"/>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Label at the bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem with this solution is that when I put a `DataGrid` in the middle (Row 1) it occupies all the remaining empty space that pushes the bottom `Label` away.

I would like the bottom `Label` to stick to the bottom of the `DataGrid` when the `DataGrid` doesn't occupy the whole height and stay on screen when `DataGrid` is taller than the screen.

Pseudo code:

```
if DataGrid needs scrollbar
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
else
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Example with numbers:

```
DataGrid needs a scrollbar:
    screen height: 1000 px
    filled data grid height: 2500 px
    sticky footer height: 30 px
    sticky footer y from top: 970 px (screen height - sticky footer height)

DataGrid does not need a scrollbar:
    screen height: 1000 px
    empty data grid height: 100 px
    sticky footer height: 30 px
    sticky footer y from top: 100 px (same as data grid height)
```

This is just an example, my screen is resizable, so the solution can't depend on screen size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DockPanel with inner Grid produce desired layout:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <Label Content="Label at the top" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Label at the bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

[image: long window]

[image: short window]

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually tried it with a DockPanel, but I forgot `LastChildFill="False"`