# Combine Grid Auto size with asterisk/star (*) size?

Tags: wpf

Say I have a Grid with three rows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <!-- Top Bar -->
    <Border Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- Some stuff -->
    </Border>
    
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <Border Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- Some stuff -->
    </Border>
    
    <!-- Bottom Bar -->
    <Border Grid.Row="2">
        <!-- Some stuff -->
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

This works fine until the main content is too large and pushes the bottom bar outside the window. To fix this, I add a ScrollViewer and change the height of the second row to take the maximum available space:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <!-- Top Bar -->
    <Border Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- Some stuff -->
    </Border>
    
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <Border Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <!-- Some stuff -->
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
    
    <!-- Bottom Bar -->
    <Border Grid.Row="2">
        <!-- Some stuff -->
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

This works great until the main content is *smaller* than the available space, in which case there's a large gap between the main content and the bottom bar.

Auto sizing sets the height to the height of the content, no matter what. Star sizing sets the height to the height of the available space, no matter what.

Is it possible to have the best of both worlds? Auto sizing that doesn't expand beyond the available space of the parent?

Comment: maybe try a different Panel? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65790870/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-sticky-footer-in-wpf)

Comment: @ASh If you put that in a proper answer I'll accept it. I didn't even consider DockPanels!

Comment: I don't actually have any code which applies to your exact issue. But you can post a self-answer if DockPanel has worked